# How to upload files to XTRF so a local file can be referenced in call to createSimpleQuote

Tags: xtrf

Trying to understand options for attatching input files can to a quote/project when using the Web Service API for Partners 1.0.

We have figured out how to use the login and the createSimpleQuote SOAP methods to create a Quote as a customer.

The thing step that we are struggling with now is how to upload the input files that are to be referenced in the files section of the payload to createSimpleQuote.

```
        <par:files>
           <par:name>?</par:name>
           <par:category>?</par:category>
           <par:url>?</par:url>
        </par:files>
```

Ideally we like the url element to reference local files (using file:///tmp/sample.pdf) as it is done in the java [usage example](http://knowledgebase.xtrf.eu/display/XTRFAPIWSP/Usage+Examples)).

What options do we have for uploading files?
How do we get the local path value of an uploaded file that can be used in the createSimpleQuote SOAP call?

Please advice?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to upload files from your local disk to XTRF via Web Service API.

In order to reference a file using `file://` protocol, the file must be visible to XTRF. There are several options to do this:

- the file should be uploaded before sending request to the XTRF Web Service API
- request to the XTRF Web Service API should be sent from the same machine where XTRF is running
- remote disk where the file is stored should be mounted (e.g. using CIFS, NFS or another network filesystem protocol) on the machine where XTRF is running

Note that it is also possible to refer to a file using other protocols, e.g. `http://` or `ftp://`.

Comment: Thank you. The first option you list is exactly what I like to do. _italic_The file should be uploaded before sending request to the XTRF Web Service API_italic_

Is there an option for uploading a file using the API? If so where is the documentation?

Comment: Could you please create an example of how a reference using ftp:// looks like assuming the FTP server requires username and password